# inserting into the middle of an array 

Tags: c++, arrays, insert, variable-assignment

I have an array `int *playerNum` which stores the list of all the numbers of the players in the team. Each slot e.g `playerNum[1];` represents a position on the team, if I wanted to add a new player for a new position on the team. That is, inserting a new element into the array somewhere near the middle, how would I go about doing this?

At the moment, I was thinking you `memcpy` up to the position you want to insert the player into a new array and then insert the new player and copy over the rest of it?

(I have to use an array)

Comment: You should use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You can't grow a C-style array (don't use those btw) nor a `std::array`.

Answer (score 3):

If you *have* to use an array, after having made sure you have enough storage (using `realloc` if necessary), use `memmove` to shift the items from the insertion point to the end by one position, then save your new player at the desired location.

You can't use `memcpy` if the source and target areas overlap.

This will fail as soon as the objects in your array have non-trivial copy-constructors, and it's not idiomatic C++. Using one of the container classes is much safer (`std::vector` or `std::list` for instance).

Comment: In case (in the future) he uses this code on types with non-trivial copy constructors, `memmove` (or `memcpy`) won't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C++, I would suggest not using `memcpy` or `memmove` but instead using the `copy` or `copy_backward` algorithms.  These will work on any data type, not just plain old integers, and most implementations are optimized enough that they will compile down to `memmove` anyway.  More importantly, they will work even if you change the underlying type of the elements in the array to something that needs a custom copy constructor or assignment operator.

Comment: No offence, but I am suggesting YOU USE THESE, but not directly. make a method / function and put C things there so if someone sees the code to understand why you doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution using `memcpy` is correct (under few assumptions mentionned by other).

However, and since you are programming in C++. It is probably a better choice to  use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/) and its `insert` method.

```
  vector<int> myvector (3,100);
  myvector.insert ( 10 , 42 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Last element will be overwritten and will be lost:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

const size_t size = 10;
int L[size];

void insert(int val, size_t index, int *array){
    memmove(
        array + index + 1,
        array + index,
        (size - index + 1) * sizeof(int)
    );

    array[index] = val;
}

int main(){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       L[i] = i;

    insert(11, 6, L);    
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
       printf("%zu %d\n", i, L[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eGhsq1aW9

Answer (score 0):

An array takes a contiguous block of memory, there is no function for you to insert an element in the middle. you can create a new one of size larger than the origin's by one then copy the original array into the new one plus the new member

```
for(int i=0;i<arSize/2;i++)
{
    newarray[i]<-ar[i];
}
newarray[i+1]<-newelemant;
for(int j=i+1<newSize;j++,i++)
{
    newarray[i]<-ar[i];
}
```

if you use STL, ting becomes easier, use list.

Comment: Regardless of data structure used, don't use a loop, use `std::copy`!

Comment: what is "var1 **<-** var2" ? Something C++11 ? And vector might be better then list (random access)

Answer (score 0):

As you're talking about an array and "insert" I assume that it is a sorted array. You don't necessarily need a second array provided that the capacity `N` of your existing array is large enough to store more entries (`N>n`, where `n` is the number of current entries). You can move the entries from `k` to `n-1` (zero-indexed) to `k+1` to `n`, where `k` is the desired insert position. Insert the new element at index position `k` and increase `n` by one. If the array is not large enough in the beginning, you can follow your proposed approach or just reallocate a new array of larger capacity `N'` and copy the existing data before applying the actual insert operation described above.

BTW: As you're using C++, you could easily use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to use arrays for this, C++ has a better solutions to offer. For starters, try `std::vector`, which is a decent enough general-purpose container, based on a dynamically-allocated array. It behaves exactly like an array in many cases.

Looking at your problem, however, there are two downsides to arrays or vectors:

- Indices have to be 0-based and contiguous; you cannot remove elements from the middle without losing key/value associations for everything after the removed element; so if you remove the player on position 4, then the player from position 9 will move to position 8
- Random insertion and deletion (that is, anywhere except the end) is expensive - O(n), that is, execution time grows linearly with array size. This is because every time you insert or delete, a part of the array needs to be moved.

If the key/value thing isn't important to you, *and* insertion/deletion isn't time critical, *and* your container is never going to be really large, then by all means, use a vector. If you need random insertion/deletion performance, but the key/value thing isn't important, look at `std::list` (although you won't get random access then, that is, the `[]` operator isn't defined, as implementing it would be very inefficient for linked lists; linked lists are also very memory hungry, with an overhead of two pointers per element). If you want to maintain key/value associations, `std::map` is your friend.

Comment: don't look at `std::list` for performance. `std::list` is a node based container, you can improve its performance with a custom pool allocator but in the end it's the slowest non-associative container for most work-loads. The advantages of `std::list` include: nearly no iterator invalidation and the `splice` operation, but certainly not general purpose performance (neither in speed or memory occupied...)

Comment: Well, if random insertion and deletion is going to be the bottleneck, then `std::list` is still interesting, performance wise.

Comment: in theory. In practice the cost of walking the list (and getting all those cache misses because the nodes are everywhere in memory) is so high that it takes a lot of copies to make up for it. Memory locality is not oft discussed in CS classes, but it's very important in practice. The `vector` has a much simpler structure which play very well with caches and `memmove` is very efficient.